# iphone UI difference between 5.1 and 6.1 simulators

Tags: iphone, simulator, ios5.1, ios6.1

I made a simple calculator for iphone and I realized a BIG difference when I ran it with iPhone 5.1 and 6.1 simulators.

Here is my calculator with [iPhone 5.1 simulator](http://www.eklsofttrade.com/lk/images/ios/calc_ui_20120317.JPG), and here is the program with [iPhone 6.1 simulator](http://www.eklsofttrade.com/lk/images/ios/Calc-iPhone6_1Sim.png).

I didn't use image for UI. All button effect for example shade is made programmatically.

What will be the problem, how can I resolve it?

I don't know this effect is depend on today I'm upgraded the XCode to version 4.6.

I using Mac OSX 10.7 Lion on Mac Mini mid 2011.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post the code that generates the buttons.

Comment: Post the code for just one button, there's no need to post them all.